Azure Pipeline - Powershell Task - Absorb Errors locally
I've got an Azure devops pipeline that runs a powershell script which - in turn - calls a number of other powershell scripts. One of the functions it calls uses Start-Process to make a call to MSDeploy to move releases onto Azure app services.
This generally works fine but occasionally stalls as we lose connection to the app service mid-deployment. I'm handling this by examining process ExitCode on completion and - if it's non-zero - I will retry the operation again up to 3 times. Working like this has always ensured the deploy completes successfully.
Despite managing this failure locally, the parent stage in the pipeline always interprets this as an error and will refuse to move on to the next stage. Does anyone know how I can call Start-Process in a way that will allow me to check if it worked like this WITHOUT killing the pipeline? I don't want to flag the stage to ignore any errors received in case there is a genuine breakdown in connectivity I couldn't overcome.
See the function below. Checking the value of $proc.ExitCode is a reliable way of determining if it completed or not, but I can't stop the error bubbling up to the stage when it happens.
function DeployService([string]$ServiceName, [array]$msdeployArgs) {
    [int]$i=1
    [bool]$Succeeded = $false
    Write-Host("Deploying service [{0}] now..." -f $ServiceName)
    for(;$i -le 3;$i++)
    {               
        $proc = Start-Process $WebDeployFilePath -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList $msdeployArgs -PassThru       
        $handle = $proc.Handle
        $proc.WaitForExit();
        if ($proc.ExitCode -eq 0) {
            $Succeeded = $true
            break
        } else {
            Write-Host("Deployment of [{0}] failed with exit code [{1}], will retry up to 3 times" -f $ServiceName, $proc.ExitCode)
            if ($i -lt 3) {
                $Error.Clear()
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        }   
    }
    return $Succeeded
}

The parent stage carries on to completion, but the Powershell task is flagged as errored, so the next stage isn't called.

Have you tried using -erroraction with start-process? You might even use try / catch to work through it.

Thanks for the suggestions @Nixphoe. I'll try them and will let you know. I just need to set up a pipeline with steps that will either succeed or fail and will go from there.

Found a solution for this in Capturing standard out and error with Start-Process
The Azure step errors simply because information is written to stderr by the process we're executing. So adding the following to the Start-Process command supresses this and allows us to dictate whether there's a fatal problem or not.
In my case, checking for a non-zero ExitCode is enough to determine a local problem, and if my retries don't work I merely inform the calling code that the operation failed. Calling code then throws an exception if failure is bubbled up this way.
 -RedirectStandardError "ErrorOut.txt"

